# How to add a fragment and an activity in a viewpager so that the fragment appears on swipe?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I want the activity to be on the screen and a fragment to appear on swipe. Can I use viewpager? Viewpagers are generally used for multiple fragments. Can an activity and fragment be added in the viewpager?

Comment: you can add viewPager in Activity and use Fragment for Multiple Swipe View

Comment: You can use `ViewPager` just to swipe between fragments, also you need to attach a ViewPagerAdapter which must return instance of `Fragment`. So definitely you can't swipe to an Activity. You should implement the swipe yourself, outside of the `ViewPager`.

Comment: Do you just need an animation for a single fragment? If that is the case you are right. you don't need a view pager. You can just listen for swipe gesture and add the fragment with an animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use viewpager, but, you cant put an activity inside a viewpager. only fragments. Its fairly easy to convert an activity to a fragment. With this you may now construct your activity in this heirarchy:

> Activity
>   -ViewPager
>   --List of Fragments